# How to compare a string variable whose value is formatted from an excel cell with a normal string variable?

Tags: java, excel, data-formatters

I want to compare the string typed by user and another string which I formatted from date to string for an excel value. I have an array of objects. Each objects has date data. I want to print these objects from the date typed by user. However, the method that I wrote for finding the index of the object is not working properly. I hope you got me. Here is my code;
`

```
System.out.print("Please enter a date:");
input = new Scanner(System.in);
String date1=input.next();
int index_tarih=searching(date1, myObjects);//myObjects is my array storing my data from excel.


public static int searching(String datess,sicaklik_nesne dayss[]) 
{   int number=0;

    for(int index_number=0;index_number<dayss.lenght;index_number++)
    {
       if(dayss[index_number].Gun==datess)
        {
            sayi=9;
        }
   }    

enter code here
    return sayi;
}
```

`

```
i.Gun=new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(cell);// this code from my class retrieving excel data.
```

Comment: "is not working properly" is a little hard to grasp. In what way doesn't it work properly (which indicates it basically works but not always in the way you expect)? What do you expect and what do you get instead? Do you have any examples on that?

Comment: For example user enters 06-Jan-86 and my searching method did not find the index whose value is 06-Jan-86. I am sure that my array consists of that date.  That date's index in my array is 5,however it returns 0 instead of 5. There is a problem comparing two string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use equals instead of == while comparing strings

```
if(dayss[index_number].Gun.equals(datess)) {
    sayi=9;
}
```

PS: if you want to compare Strings doesn't matter it is uppercase or lowercase you can use `equalsIgnoreCase()` method instead of equals here.